# How can I complete site verification in Google Search Console (Webmaster Tools) API version 3?

Tags: javascript, google-search-console, google-search-api

I'm working with the Search Console API to add sites and get information from them once added. Unfortunately, the API Reference is rather sparse and so far all I can do is submit the site for initial verification - then once I upload the verification file or meta tag, I have to go log into the google account and click the "Verify" button manually, defeating the purpose of the API.

I know that previous versions of the API allowed you to complete the verification by sending another request. As the documentation for v3 is missing a large amount of information and is often incorrect in general, I'm hoping someone else knows how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Google Site Verification](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/getting_started) instead.

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/siteVerification/v1/token?access_token=oauth2-token
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "verificationMethod": "META",
  "site": {
    "identifier": "http://www.example.com",
    "type": "SITE"
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "token": '<meta name="google-site-verification" content="lZgPSX9UM01PXeMi88RGdIrBpl7jLFCXL9RNt4N0mmo" />',
  "method": "META"
}
```

Read this for more information:
https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/invoking#verify

Answer (score 1):

The method for verifying site ownership has been deprecated in the older API versions and is no longer supported.
Therefore there is no longer away for verifying site ownership via API.

See [Developer's Guide: Protocol](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol) to learn more.

Comment: This Deveoper's Guide is for the v2 API. I'm looking for a solution that applies to the v3 API.

Comment: That it was already deprecated in v2 API clearly indicates for me that it was never available in v3 API.

Comment: I'm looking for factual information, not leaps of faith or guesses, but thanks for your time.